# How to compile third party c library in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, c, sip

i tried to do a sip client for iphone. 
I tried to use oSip or eXosip2 , i download their package ,and compile it using "./configure""make""make install "

I get some *.a library, and i include there headers.

When i compile it , their is warning , this *.a library formate doesn't support !

It's really annoying, what should i do to make it work ?

Should i include their code ,and compile in xcode ,tried to build a static library ?

somebody tell me ,how to deal with some C librarys.

I see some topics talk about how to make a library in xcode . The problem is , if it is C library , it was already done, no need to build in xcode ,it's already their ,just make to build it . Whatif the *.a library doesn't support ,what should i do ??

PS: I was already doing the static library ,not dynamically. It's not a chooice between dynamically and static . It's all about x86_64 PC LIB is not suitable for i386 iphone.

Comment: Did you succeed with oSIP on iOS?

Answer (score 3):

You can't dynamically link on the iPhone; it has to be static linking.

> Should i include their code ,and compile in xcode ,tried to build a static library ?

Yes, I think so.

Maybe have a look at this previous question: [How do I add a third party Framework to iPhone project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/505974/how-do-i-add-a-third-party-framework-to-iphone-project)

Comment: I didn't try to build dynamically library. I compile, make ,to build a " *.a" library.My question is :

after i compile ,and get this *.a library , it's ok to use in Mac application which is "x86_64".

When i use that static library in iPhone or Mac application i386, it just doesn't recognize that format.

How to compile pjsip.org that framework for iphone ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to compile for iOS, you should create an **xcode project**. It will be much easier to use, maintain and debug.

You can download here my [osip/exosip/c-ares xcode project](http://sip.antisip.com/xcode/).

The above also requires [c-ares](http://c-ares.haxx.se/) which is an important dependancy for eXosip2.

PS: minor update may be required to compile git version. Just add/remove new/old files.